# Subalgebra of a nuclear $C^*$-algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Is every exact $C^*$-algebra a subalgebra of a nuclear  $C^*$-algebra?

I know the conclusion is true when the exact $C^*$-algebra is separable, since every separable exact $C^*$-algebra  is a subalgebra of $\mathcal{O}_2$.

If a exact $C^*$-algebra is non-separable, does the above conclusion also hold?

Comment: Pisier implies that this is still open in his new book "Tensor Products of C*-algebras and Operator Spaces", so unless it's been solved in the past few months it's probably still open.

Comment: @Cameron Zwarich, May I ask you a question : in which page does Pisier mention that the problem is still open ?

Comment: I'm using the PDF on his website. It's at the beginning of the chapter on Exactness and Nuclearity and in the notes at the end. He doesn't say that it's still open explicitly, but he mentioned it as open in his previous book on operator spaces (right after he states the embedding theorem for separable algebras) and doesn't say anything here.